# How to return a value from a Django view?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to call a view from a JavaScript file using Ajax, but i want the view to return only a value called **"this"**. But when I do this, It throws an error saying **view** didn't return an **HttpResponse object**, it returned **None** instead.

Is it possible to just return a value from a view instead without a Html page?

[View Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVv3r.png)

[Javascript/Ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8sXw.png)

Answer (score 1):

> A view function, or view for short, is simply a Python function that takes a Web request and returns a Web response.
>   Each view function is responsible for returning an HttpResponse object.

In your code, you just return a value instead of `HttpResponse`. The correct code would be :

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def result(request):
    if request=="POST":
       return HttpResponse("something you want to view")
```

Comment: I changed the code to " return HttpResponse " but i am still getting an error.

Comment: For test: I added
 return HttpResponse("testing")
But now the error thrown is : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split

Comment: which django version you currently using in your project ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `runAreaReview(param)` is supposed to return, but assuming it would return a string for example, then this should work:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def result(request):
    param = ...
    this = ...'
    return HttpResponse( this )
```